# Object recognition object detected but wrong position

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to set up object recognition on a robot created in fusion 360 using the find_object_2d package, Iam able to detect my object (coke can); however, when i open rviz, the tf of the object is recognized as above the camera rather than in front of it.
Below is my urdf and 3d detection launch file.
URDF:

> ```
> <gazebo reference="camera_1">
> ```

```
   <material>${body_color}</material>
   <mu1>0.2</mu1>
   <mu2>0.2</mu2>
   <selfCollide>true</selfCollide>
    </gazebo>
```

> ```
> <gazebo reference="camera_1">
> ```

```
   <sensor name="camera_1" type="depth">
   <update_rate>20</update_rate>
   <camera>
   <horizontal_fov>1.047198</horizontal_fov>
   <image>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>480</height>
    <format>R8G8B8</format>
  </image>
  <clip>
    <near>0.05</near>
    <far>3</far>
  </clip>
  </camera>
  <plugin name="camera_1_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_openni_kinect.so">
  <baseline>0.2</baseline>
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>1.0</updateRate>
  <cameraName>camera_1_ir</cameraName>
  <imageTopicName>/camera_1/color/image_raw</imageTopicName>
  <cameraInfoTopicName>/camera_1/color/camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
  <depthImageTopicName>/camera_1/depth/image_raw</depthImageTopicName>
  <depthImageInfoTopicName>/camera_1/depth/camera_info</depthImageInfoTopicName>
  <pointCloudTopicName>/camera_1/depth/points</pointCloudTopicName>
  <frameName>camera_1</frameName>
  <pointCloudCutoff>0.5</pointCloudCutoff>
  <pointCloudCutoffMax>3.0</pointCloudCutoffMax>
  <distortionK1>0.00000001</distortionK1>
  <distortionK2>0.00000001</distortionK2>
  <distortionK3>0.00000001</distortionK3>
  <distortionT1>0.00000001</distortionT1>
  <distortionT2>0.00000001</distortionT2>
  <CxPrime>0</CxPrime>
  <Cx>0</Cx>
  <Cy>0</Cy>
  <focalLength>0</focalLength>
  <hackBaseline>0</hackBaseline>
</plugin>
```

> ```
>   <link name="camera_1">
> ```

```
     <inertial>
     <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.012500000000000011 0.0 0.0"/>
     <mass value="0.3575"/>
     <inertia ixx="0.001266" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="9.3e-05" iyz="0.0" izz="0.00121"/>
     </inertial>
    <visual>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.25 -0.0 -0.15"/>
    <geometry>
    <mesh filename="package://moodz_description/meshes/camera_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
    </geometry>
    <material name="silver"/>
    </visual>
   <collision>
   <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.25 -0.0 -0.15"/>
  <geometry>
  <mesh filename="package://moodz_description/meshes/camera_1.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
  </geometry>
  </collision>
  </link>
```

> 

```
 <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.25 0.0 0.15"/>
 <parent link="base_link"/>
<child link="camera_1"/>
</joint>
```

Launch Files:
3d Object_Recognition:

> ```
>  <launch>
> ```

```
<node name="find_object_3d" pkg="find_object_2d" type="find_object_2d" output="screen">
    <param name="gui" value="true" type="bool"/>
    <param name="settings_path" value="~/.ros/find_object_2d.ini" type="str"/>
    <param name="subscribe_depth" value="true" type="bool"/>
    <param name="session_path" value="$(find obj_detection)/sessions/coke_session.bin" type="str"/>
    <param name="objects_path" value="" type="str"/>
    <param name="object_prefix" value="object" type="str"/>
    <remap from="rgb/image_rect_color" to="/camera_1/color/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="depth_registered/image_raw" to="/camera_1/depth/image_raw"/>
    <remap from="depth_registered/camera_info" to="/camera_1_ir/depth/camera_info"/>
            </node>
<!-- Example of tf synchronisation with the objectsStamped message <node name="tf_example" pkg="find_object_2d" type="tf_example" output="screen">
    <param name="map_frame_id" value="/camera_1" type="string"/>
    <param name="object_prefix" value="object" type="str"/>
</node>-->

<launch>
    <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro $(find moodz_description)/urdf/moodz.xacro" name="robot_description"/>
    <node args="-param robot_description -urdf -model moodz" name="spawn_urdf" pkg="gazebo_ros"         type="spawn_model"/>
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="paused" value="true"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
    </include>
     <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"/
```

Rviz:
![image description](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1644430393912427.png)![image description](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/16444342486676973.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395921/object-recognition-object-detected-but-wrong-position/) by [ROS_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/79161/ros_newbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2022-02-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-02-09**:
Added points. Can you pls add the image to your question. Thank you

**Comment by [ROS_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/79161/ros_newbie/) on 2022-02-09**:
Image can now be viewed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This was solved by publishing a static transform between the camera and base_link according to the following command to your launch file:

This publishes a transform from your base_link to camera_link and rotates according to the above angles.

---

Originally posted by [ROS_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/79161/ros_newbie/) with karma: 23 on 2022-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1